# PHP mail not working as expected

Tags: php, sendmail

Turns out that the problem wasn't a generic PHP problem. It was a problem with my host. :<

Answer (score 0):

Error 200 means that the PHP script sent no output to the web Server

Add this to the php.ini `register_globals=on`